List of 100 teams, each team has 10 players, each player has 10 performance metrics. How can I structure this using pandas Dataframes?

Effectively I already have one dataframe with team names against player names and another with player names against performance metrics

Long format. Add another column called “metric” which lists what material is being measured. Add another column for the value of that metric.

you should put all your data in a 'tall' format, then you can handle as many dimensions as you want
column 1 team, column 2 player, column 3 metric,
column 4 metric value
eg
team 1| bob| goals scored| 3
team 1| bob| average speed| 15
....
team 1| john| average speed| 16
